# Plato, a student of Socrates and a teacher of Aristole

Tags: plato

Did Plato believe in a lot of questioning, just like Socrates?

Comment: Hi Ethan, welcome to the site.  A question like this needs more details in order to draw good answers.  Can you provide a little background that would lead to more than just a "yes" or "no" answer?

Answer (score 1):

Much of our knowledge of Socrates derives from Plato's dialogues, so it is hard to say how much questioning or of exactly what kind Socrates did. The legend is that Socrates was stimulated in his career of questioning by the oracle of Apollo at Delphi. When asked whether anyone was wiser than Socrates, the oracle answered that there was none wiser. This puzzled Socrates, who didn't think he had any wisdom or knowledge at all. He went about among the supposedly wise in Athens and, by questioning them, discovered that they had no wisdom or knowledge at all. He then set about questioning anyone he could about philosophical matters such as the definition of holiness, courage, virtue.

We have a good many dialogues which Plato wrote after Socrates' death. These are full of questions, with the main questioner generally given the name of 'Socrates'.

One difference is that Socrates questioned whoever would discuss philosophy with him. He was very much a mixer with ordinary people. Plato discussed, and used question and answer, among select friends and the students at his 'Academy', which has been called the first university. Unlike Socrates he separated his philosophical inquiries from engagement with the general citizenry.

Another difference is that while Socrates wrote nothing (nothing that has survived, anyway), so that his questioning was all 'live' - a matter of talking with people, much of Plato's questioning was done in writing, hence the dialogues which he composed; these were literary productions.

Hope this helps. Chris Sunami is right : you need to ask more detailed questions if you're to get the best out of the site. So, more detail next time, please.